# what's this matlab code doing?

Tags: matlab

I'm fairly new to matlab and wrote this following code:

```
datadir=('/.../prod/balanceSheet/DB/');

seriesnames = {'a.m','b.m','c.m','d.m','f.m','g.m','h.m','i.m'};

for proj=1:5;
database='';
switch proj
  case 1
    database=strcat(datadir,'scenario1');
  case 2
    database=strcat(datadir,'scenario2');
  case 3
    database=strcat(datadir,'scenario3');
  case 4
    database=strcat(datadir,'scenario4');
  case 5
    database=strcat(datadir,'scenario5');
end;

database;
gooddatanames={};
a=length(seriesnames);
for i=1:a
    gooddatanames={gooddatanames,database,seriesnames(i)};
end
end
```

this is my first time using a switch. basically what I'm trying to do is to take series from databases (1,2,3,...) such that all series are subject to all scenarios. I'm missing the function that would pull the data but is the above code doing the intended?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
gooddatanames={gooddatanames,database,seriesnames(i)};
```

to

```
gooddatanames={gooddatanames{:},database,seriesnames{i}};
```

and move `gooddatanames = {}` outside of the loop, and then it does what I think you expect, which is to produce a 1x80 cell array with alternating folders and file names.

---

More likely, make a few more changes, like this:

```
datadir=('/.../prod/balanceSheet/DB/');

seriesnames = {'a.m','b.m','c.m','d.m','f.m','g.m','h.m','i.m'};
gooddatanames={};

for proj=1:5;
    database='';
    switch proj
        case 1
            database=fullfile(datadir,'scenario1');
        case 2
            database=fullfile(datadir,'scenario2');
        case 3
            database=fullfile(datadir,'scenario3');
        case 4
            database=fullfile(datadir,'scenario4');
        case 5
            database=fullfile(datadir,'scenario5');
    end;

    for i=1:length(seriesnames);
        gooddatanames{end+1} = fullfile(database,seriesnames{i});
    end
end
```

which results in a 1x40 array of full paths to the individual files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Pursuit has written, though I would like to add that your for/switch structure is a little silly.  If you effectively have to enumerate all of them, as you do with the 'switch' as you've implemented it, there's no reason not to take the for/switch loops out entirely and just leave yourself with the commands.  One possible alternative would be to replace the entire unnecessary "switch" with:

```
database = fullfile(datadir, ['scenario', num2str(proj)]);
```